# Downgrading Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation

I'd like to downgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 back to an older version. i.e. 13.04.

Can I just boot ubuntu installer, uninstall Ubuntu 13.10 and install 13.04 without any problems to my home folder?

Answer (score 0):

that depend on if you have a separate partition for your home folder. If not your home folder will be erased during the installation.

Keeping/placing back all .hidden folders is not always a good idea, since the config-files in it are not necessarily compatible with newer/older versions of the program they belong to. I recommend only keeping those config files you really need/want to keep.